# Mocking same interface more than once in Rhino

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I want to mock the same interface more than once. The code below demonstrates what I think is stopping me.

I've had a read around and can't find a solution to this. It would appear there is no way to differentiate between _mockOne and _mockTwo.

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
}

[TestFixture]
class RhinoTest
{
    private IDoSomething _mockOne;
    private IDoSomething _mockTwo;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _mockOne = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDoSomething>();
        _mockTwo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDoSomething>();

        var somethings = new Dictionary<string, IDoSomething>
                         {
                             {"one", _mockOne},
                             {"two", _mockTwo}
                         };

        //Pass this dictionary to a constructor for use in tests
    }
}
```

If I debug the code, I find that the two objects have the same identifier.

[image: Image of IDoSomething mocks with same identifiers]

I realise this may be more to do with poor abstraction but it would be really helpful at our project's current position if there is a way around this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI I am currently investigating whether this answer could solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/3882743/966609

Comment: The above doesn't seem to have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being thrown off course by the applications complexity.

I was actually an equality issue. The parameters I am expecting are complex objects which actually fail an `Assert.AreEqual(...);`

In the hope of speeding up someone else in this same situation. Here is a test which *fails*.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var expectedInput = new Object1 { DeeperObject = new Object2 { MyString = "Hello World" } };

    const string expectedOutput = "Hello Matt!";

    _mockOne.Expect(s => s.ReturnSomething(expectedInput))
            .Return(expectedOutput);

    var actualInput = new Object1 { DeeperObject = new Object2 { MyString = "Hello World" } };

    var actualOutput = _mockOne.ReturnSomething(actualInput);

    Assert.NotNull(actualOutput);
}
```

To fix this, the parameter properties need to matched specifically.

Replace the line starting `_mockOne.Expect` with:

`_mockOne.Expect(s => s
    .ReturnSomething(Arg<Object1>
    .Matches(o => o.DeeperObject.MyString == expectedInput.DeeperObject.MyString)))
    .Return(expectedOutput);`

Done.

Comment: If anyone can answer why overriding the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods does not help I'd like to hear why.